# Getting user details from when using django rest simplejwt and react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a simple authentication app by following some tutorials.
I have my user register and login set up as follows:

**Register.js**

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
      .post('user/register/' , {
        email:formData.email,
        name : formData.name,
        password : formData.password
      })
      .then((res) =>{
        history('/login');
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  };
```

**Login.js**

```
const handleSubmit =(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    axiosInstance
    .post('token/',{
      email:formData.email,
      password:formData.password
    })
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(formData.email)
      localStorage.setItem('access_token',res.data.access);
      localStorage.setItem('refresh_token',res.data.refresh);
      axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
      'JWT '+localStorage.getItem('access_token');
      navigate('/');
    })
  }
```

**axios.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL : baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers : {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        ? 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') : null ,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        accept:'application/json',
    },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                    'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                    'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'token/refresh/'
        ) {
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

**RegisterSerializer**

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields=('email','name','password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password':{'write_only':True}}

    def create(self , validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password',None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/user/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

The register login logout functionalities seems to be working correctly but the issue is that I dont know how to get user details in the frontend like if I simple want to display the logged in users username on navbar how do I get it>

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is, when you login and navigate to the home route. You can just call the an API, probably in the `onMount` event in home component, which would take the token as payload/header.

You can check and decrypt the token in the BE, and send the user data to the Frontend. You can store the received response in your state and print the username in the Navbar